# Main disk letter suddenly changed and extraneous disk devices appeared

Tags: udev, devices

For some reason, my main disk, which used to be `/dev/sda`, is suddenly now `/dev/sde`. There are no other disks attached to the computer. Looking into the `/dev` directory, there seem to be four extraneous devices (`/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdd`), and the minor device number of my main disk seems to be a lot higher than what I think it should be on a system with no other disks attached (64 to 68 instead of 0 to 4).

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 May 20 20:06 /dev/sda  # ?
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 May 20 20:06 /dev/sdb  # ?
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32 May 20 20:06 /dev/sdc  # ?
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 48 May 20 20:06 /dev/sdd  # ?
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 64 May 20 20:06 /dev/sde  # Main disk here, formerly /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 65 May 20 20:06 /dev/sde1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 66 May 20 20:06 /dev/sde2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 67 May 20 20:06 /dev/sde3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 68 May 20 20:06 /dev/sde4
```

Attempting to peer into the extraneous disk devices will result in an error saying that there is no  medium (e.g. using `fdisk -l` will result in `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdX: No medium found`), which was expected.

Do note that there is nothing really *wrong* or damaged here (or so I hope). My system boots just fine, and my `/etc/fstab` refers to my root partition by UUID anyway, so really there's nothing wrong here. I'm just wondering why an `a` had suddenly changed to an `e`.

Certainly, things like this probably don't happen out of the figurative blue, and the last thing I recall doing, whether it may provide a clue to this or not, was installing `uswsusp`, configuring it a bit, testing it out, and then removing it. I may have done a `sudo update-initramfs -u` and a `sudo update-grub` here and there in between, but I don't really see anything that could have done this. My `udev` rules do not seem to have been altered, but I could be wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: BIOS changes can cause drive letters (sdx) to change, as can additional hardware (or changes to hardware detected by BIOS).  This is one reason why UUID's are preferred.   If you didn't add or remove hardware, nor make a change to the BIOS/uefi configuration, then you may have a soon-to-fail battery in the machine, OR some other component approaching failure (which may be very soon, to months-years away - if not just battery).   *I don't know `uswsusp` so have ignored that piece of information*

Comment: Well, I haven't touched the BIOS in quite a while, and I highly doubt that it would be the battery's fault (it's a desktop PC, so it wouldn't really have one).

Comment: He probably meant the cmos battery.

Comment: Desktop motherboards use typically a CR2032 battery.

Comment: Yep CMOS battery which usually holds BIOS settings (keeps clock running etc on motherboard).  Servers can have many batteries.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought about that. Would that be a likely reason, though, given the above symptoms? How strange.